# How to get array out of array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, filtering

I am working with an array that is formatted like this

```
[
[{
    "ID": "f75d414d-55fc-43c8-a24d-34eca67913b7",
    "Revision": "a8c73a24-d46a-47c8-825e-511b26485e23",
    "type": "Hello",
    "Stage": null,
    "label": null,
},
{
    "ID": "f75d414d-55fc-43c8-a24d-34eca67913b7",
    "Revision": "a8c73a24-d46a-47c8-825e-511b26485e23",
    "type": "world",
    "Stage": null,
    "label": null,
}]
]
```

That I need converted to this

```
[{
    "ID": "f75d414d-55fc-43c8-a24d-34eca67913b7",
    "Revision": "a8c73a24-d46a-47c8-825e-511b26485e23",
    "type": "Hello",
    "Stage": null,
    "label": null,
},
{
    "ID": "f75d414d-55fc-43c8-a24d-34eca67913b7",
    "Revision": "a8c73a24-d46a-47c8-825e-511b26485e23",
    "type": "world",
    "Stage": null,
    "label": null,
}]
```

by saving a variable (the original array) to itself some way.  A slick way would be nice.

Comment: Just do `arrayName = arrayName[0]`

Comment: You are basically asking how to access the first element of an array. This should be [covered by any JavaScript tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Predefined_Core_Objects#Referring_to_Array_Elements).

Comment: `var a = [[{ID:...},{ID:...}]][0];`

Comment: Is it actually a **JS Array**, or is it **JSON** text? If it's JSON, then the obvious thing to do would be to parse it, though with such a minor change, you could really do it with string manipulation too, like `data.trim().slice(1,-1)`. But if you're ultimately going to parse it anyway, you might as well just go ahead and do that.

Answer (score 1):

Off the top of my head wouldn't `originalArray = originalArray[0]` save the inner array back to the original variable?